# Regext to match only ONE occurance of a pattern

Tags: regex, linux

How to write a regex that says that given pattern is present ONLY once?

for e.g.. if am searching for pattern 'file',

```
      123file345 --> Match
      asdffile12 --> match
      file12file --> does not match
```

Comment: which tool you want to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!(?:.*?file){2}).*?file.*$
```

[Test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zA3tE6/1)

You may apply the above regex in grep.

```
grep -P '^(?!(?:.*?file){2}).*?file' file
```

---

The negative lookahead assertion at `^` start `(?!(?:.*?file){2})` looks ahead, if there's not
 2x ( `.*?` [lazily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) any amount of any characters, followed by substring `file` ).
If this condition succeeds, it matches `.*?file.*` all string if it contains substring `file`.

For just matching the line the last greedy dot (to match any characters after `file`) is not required.

[image]

Comment: i  thought of it too :P it would perform better :)

Comment: `-P` alone helps to print the whole line where a match was found. That's why I removed the last `.*`

Comment: Thanks Jonny. Can you please explain this? Am a noob in these expressions.

Comment: @LPD I added a bit of explanation :]

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:(?!file).)*file(?:(?!file).)*$
```

You can use this with `grep -P` .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/30

Comment: Hi Thanks. Sorry, but I want to use Linux shell to get this. Can I do that?

Comment: @LPD you need to use it with `grep -P` if you have

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the invert option of grep:

```
grep -v 'file.*file' file
```